# updateSingleValue() returns false, yet inputs are correct

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm using updateSingleValue like this:

```
$updated = $this->app['storage']->updateSingleValue('suggestions', $id, 'votes', $value);
```

The `$id` and `$value` are set correctly (even if I set them to correct integers manually), and there definitely exists a `suggestions` contenttype with `votes` field. Yet, this function returns `false`, suggesting that `!$this->isValidColumn($field, $contenttype)` fails.

A `suggestion` in json format looks like this:

```
suggestion": {
"id": "25",
"values": {
    "datechanged": "2015-01-03 13:25:02",
    "id": "25",
    "slug": "slug-o2sbdb",
    "datecreated": "2015-01-03 13:25:02",
    "datepublish": "2015-01-03 13:25:02",
    "datedepublish": "1900-01-01 00:00:00",
    "ownerid": "1",
    "status": "published",
    "title": "test title",
    "description": "test description",
    "votes": "0"
},
```

The suggestion contenttype looks like this:

```
suggestions:
    name: Suggestions
    slug: suggestions
    singular_name: Suggestion
    singular_slug: suggestion
    default_status: publish
    fields:
        title:
            label: Title
            type: text
            class: large
            required: true
            pattern: ".{2,255}" # see: http://html5pattern.com/
            error: "The Title field is required, and must contain at least 2 characters"
        description:
            label: Description
            type: textarea
        votes:
            label: Votes
            type: integer
```

What can I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem here the contenttype passed into updateSingleValue needs to be the entire contenttype not just the slug 'suggestions'. You can fetch it via the storage class method:

```
$app['storage']->getContentType('suggestions')
```

then pass in the result of that to the updateSingleValue method.